# Is there a limitation with ActivityPartySet?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dynamics-crm-2011

I am using the [Organization Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrieve(v=crm.5).aspx) to query the ActivityPartySet, and getting this error:

> ": "The 'Retrieve' method does not support entities of type
>   'activityparty'.",

**Is it possible to query the ActivityPartySet?**

Here's the retrieve:

```
_organizationService.Retrieve("activityparty", id, columnSet))
```

Comment: Can you post your retrieve query?

Comment: @thanks for looking! just updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error message says,`Retrieve` method is not supported for the entity type `ActivityParty` (which is more of an intersect entity internally). Try to query the activity party type set directly (`phonecall`, `email` etc.).

```
_organizationService.Retrieve("email", id, columnSet));
_organizationService.Retrieve("phonecall", id, columnSet));
```

Alternatively you can query using early bound [XrmServiceContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695819(v=crm.7).aspx):

```
var fetchedActivityParty = xrmServiceContext.ActivityPartySet.FirstOrDefault(activityParty => activityParty.Id == id);
```